# Convert datepicker time to mysql datetime format in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way I can convert a date in this format: 08/19/2014 1:45 pm

into MySQL datetime format like 2014-08-19 13:45:00.

I tried using something like

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $myTime);
```

but I don't think it likes the 'pm' and gives back 1969-12-31, giving error:

"A non well formed numeric value encountered"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried using `strtotime()`?

```
$myTime = strtotime("08/19/2014 1:45 pm"); 
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $myTime);
```

---

**Output**:

```
2014-08-19 13:45:00
```

Comment: In the case of using DateTimePicker, this helps to convert date time string to proper datetime data before saving it into mysql database.

Answer (score 2):

This works on dd/mm/yyyy

```
$date = '18/03/2016 16:25';
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$date)));

=> 2016-03-18 16:25:00
```